Is there a flood history similar to the Bible in the Vedas?
According to The Bible of Bibles;, by Kersey Graves, there is a flood history in the Vedas. He mention the name Sherma, Charma and Jyapheta.. TRUE?
In his book, he is writing a long list of similarities, How can I have it verified?
I would be very thankful for any answer or verification.
All the best,
Trygve Larsen

Yes the story of Manu and the flood is mentioned in Shatapata Brahmana which is considered as Vedic literature.

The Shatapatha Brahmana (Sanskrit: शतपथब्राह्मणम्, lit. 'Brāhmaṇa of
one hundred paths', IAST: Śatapatha Brāhmaṇam, abbreviated to 'SB')
is a commentary on the Śukla Yajurveda. It is attributed to the Vedic
sage Yajnavalkya. Described as the most complete, systematic, and
important of the Brahmanas (commentaries on the Vedas), it contains
detailed explanations of Vedic sacrificial rituals, symbolism, and
mythology. Source

The story is present in Shatapata Brahmana, Kanda I, adhyaya 8, brahmana 1, Shloka 1 - 6

THE IḌĀ.

In the morning they brought to Manu1 water for washing, just as now also they (are wont to) bring (water) for washing the hands. When
he was washing himself, a fish came into his hands.

It spake to him the word, 'Rear me, I will save thee!' 'Wherefrom wilt thou save me?' 'A flood will carry away all these creatures2:
from that I will save thee!' 'How am I to rear thee?'

It said, 'As long as we are small, there is great destruction for us: fish devours fish. Thou wilt first keep me in a jar. When I
outgrow that, thou wilt dig a pit and keep me in it. When I outgrow
that, thou wilt take me down to the sea, for then I shall be beyond
destruction.'

It soon became a jhaṣa (a large fish); for that grows largest (of all fish)3. Thereupon it said, 'In such and such a year that flood
will come. Thou shalt then attend to me (i.e. to my advice) by
preparing a ship[4]; and when the flood has risen thou shalt enter
into the ship, and I will save thee from it.'

After he had reared it in this way, he took it down to the sea. And in the same year which the fish had indicated to him, he attended to
(the advice of the fish) by preparing a ship; and when the flood had
risen, he entered into the ship. The fish then swam up to him, and to
its horn he tied the rope of the ship, and by that means he[5] passed
swiftly up to yonder northern mountain.

It then said, 'I have saved thee. Fasten the ship to a tree; but let not the water cut thee off[6], whilst thou art on the mountain. As
the water subsides, thou mayest gradually descend!' Accordingly he
gradually descended, and hence that (slope) of the northern mountain
is called 'Alarm's descent[7].' The flood then swept away all these
creatures, and Manu alone remained here.




Yes, indeed a great flood is mentioned in Hindu scriptures. This deluge is mentioned in many Puranas. However, a detailed description is given in the Kalika Purana. Here I am narrating the event from the Kalika Purana (chapters 32 and 33).
The great Sage Kapila, once cursed the Svayambhuva Manu that this world would be destroyed and submerged.

The entire world along with gods, mankind, and demons, no sooner, shall be killed and annihilated and destroyed. 32.28


That, who raised this earth (from the ocean), who stabilised her, who provides food for the creatures, and who preserves her-lest all of them kill this movable and immovable world together. O Manu! Within no time you will find the three worlds killed, annihilated and destroyed and then submerged in water. Surely this will purge your pride. 32.29-30

Then Manu went to the source of the Ganges, did severe austerity and prayed to Vishnu.

Janardana then appeared before Svayambhuva Manu, who was practising austerity, in the form of a small fish of green hue of durva grass, was with two bright eyes resembling the buds of karpura (camphor). 32.45-46


Then the Fish spoke to the great Svayambhuva Manu who seemed to be frightened, with compassion in a voice soaked with emotion. 32.47


O great ascetic! O distinguished one! the big fish have dreaded me everyday, I am frightened by their attempt of swallowing me, you should save me. 32.48


Svayambhuva Manu having heard these words of the fish became afflicted with great compassion and told the fish, "I shall protect you.". 32.53


Manu put some water on the cavity of his palm and placed the tiny fish in that water and observed it playing. 32.54


Thereafter the kind-hearted Manu put the fine fish in a wide aquarium full with water. 32.55

But the fish increased in size day by day.

Manu having seen the fat fish took it up in his hand and proceeded to a lake full of blossoming lotuses. 33.1

However, within a few days, the fish became too big to stay in that lake.

The lord Janardana, the embodiment of the world, who incarnated in the form of a fish, became light at the hand of Svayambhuva Manu. 33.9


Manu caught the fish by both his hands, put it on his shoulder, proceeded to the ocean and placed it in the water (of the ocean). 33. 10


In a short period of time the fish with its full grown huge body covered the entire ocean. 33.13

Then Manu realized that this is not an ordinary fish. This fish was the incarnation of lord Visnu.

O noble sir! taking into consideration the massivity and the light weight of your body I do not think you to be a fish. 33.17

The fish said

I am that eternal Hari, whom you should always propitiate. I have now manifested myself, in restraint, for the fulfillment of your desires. 33.19

Visnu then instructed Manu on what to do when the great flood would submerge the entire creation.

O Manu! you now hear me with attention what you shall have to do till the time the great flood prolongs, I am just telling you. 33.44


Construct a boat with sacrificial woods, I shall make the boat firm and strong, so that it is not wrecked by the water. 33.45


Make it ten yojanas in breadth and thirty yojanas in length so that it accommodates all the living beings, and replenish the three worlds (in future). 33.46


O Manu! twist quickly one big rope with the massive fibres of the barks of the trees, pure to sacrifice, mind that the rope must be nine yojanas in length and three vyayama (a particular length of measure; two arm-length) in circumference. The illusory power of the world, who is jagaddhatri (upholdress of the world), the mother of the world, who resides all over the world will make the rope strong so that it does not break easily. 33.47-48


The flood having been occurred you should collect the seeds of everything along with the Vedas and the seven sages, and then put them in the boat. 33.49


O Manu! After consulting Daksa you recall me, on being recalled I shall come to you immediately, you shall be able to recognise me by my green horn. 33.50


Till the time the worlds are annihilated, killed and destroyed I shall carry the boat on my back, do not harbour any doubt about this. 33.51


By the time when the flood will completely submerge the world, you must tie up the boat firmly to my horn with that rope. 33.52


The boat having been tied up to my horn I shall carry it for one thousand years by the standard of the gods and dry up the water. 33.53


O Manu! thereafter the flood water having been receded I shall bound the boat to the highest peak of the Himalayas. 33.54

Manu followed his instructions and constructed the boat.

Hari having been disappeared lord Svayambhuva got the boat and the rope manufactured as has been advised by Hari earlier. 33.57

Later, when the untimely flood happened due to the curse of sage Kapila, Svayambhuva Manu - the protector of mankind, saved humanity.
Reference -

Kalika Purana translated by B. N. Sastri


Similair to both Noah and Joana and the Whale.

Although certainly not the same!
